# In git, do we checkout/pull branches in the same directory as the master?

Tags: git, svn, github, git-branch

In SVN, after creating a branch, I generally checkout the branch to a separate directory on my system, i.e., trunk and branch don't share the same path.

In GIT, based on what I've been reading/trying, it seems like you checkout to switch to the new branch and pull the changes to the same directory.

It seems like magic to just type `git checkout <master/branch_name>` and end up with the right tree.

Is that true, or have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct. With Git, you have the entire repository on your client machine. You can checkout and commit straight to that without a central server.

Comment: Ah, sweet, thanks for confirming that. That's just beautiful to work with. We currently use SVN for a large code base at work, and each branch checkout eats up 10 GB of disk space.
With git, it seems like this would be a LOT lesser! Why can't SVN allow branches to co-exist with the trunk (i.e., the idea of a single directory housing the repository)?

Comment: In SVN you should be able to do a `Switch` which will do an in place branch checkout. I've never had a problem with that...

Comment: `svn switch ^/branches/mybranchname` and then `svn switch ^/trunk` to go back (`^/` is short hand for the full URL for the repository root so the above examples presume your project is at the root of the repo.  If you have multiple projects with different trunk and branches dirs then you'd probably want to use `^/project/branches/mybranch` and `^/project/trunk`.  With 1.7 and newer you may want to run `svn cleanup` periodically to avoid pristines building up (see http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#wc-pristines)

Comment: Damn, I've been doing it all wrong with SVN then. I've checked out each out the branches to separate directories on my disk instead of using svn switch.

Comment: I recently came from SVN too (and I'm not looking back!).  1st comment is true, you do not need a remote repo, but if you are collaborating you need to perform a git push after committing to get those revisions into remote repo.

Comment: @Raja I wouldn't say you were doing it all wrong.  You can do it either way.  If you want both available at the same time you're going to want to do separate checkouts (or a sparse checkout with both, won't get into that here).

Comment: Well, most of my branches last a week - for them, i could have definitely used switch instead of a separate checkout.